# Find words from file a in file b and output the missing word matches from file a

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have two files that I am trying to run a find/grep/fgrep on. I have been trying several different commands to try to get the following results:

## File A

```
hostnamea
hostnameb
hostnamec
hostnamed
hostnamee
hostnamef
```

## File B

```
hostnamea-20170802
hostnameb-20170802 
hostnamec-20170802.xml # some files have extensions
020214-_hostnamed-20170208.tar # some files have different extensions and have different date structure
HOSTNAMEF-20170802
```

*about files- date=20170802 - most all have this date format - some have different date format *

FileA is my control file - I want to search fileb with the whole word `hostnamea-f` and match the `hostnamea-f` in fileb and output the non-matches from `filea` into the output on terminal to be used in a shell script.

For this example I made it so `hostnamee` is not within fileb. I want to run an fgrep/grep/awk - whatever can work for this - and output only the missing `hostnamee` from filea.

I can get this to work but it does not particularly do what I need and if I swap it around I get nothing.

```
user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ fgrep -f filea fileb -i -w -o
hostnamea
hostnameb
hostnamec
hostnamed
HOSTNAMEF
```

Cool - I get the matches in File-B but what if I try to reverse it.

```
host@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ fgrep -f fileb filea -i -w -o
host@host:/netops/backups/scripts$
```

I have tried several different commands but cannot seem to get it right. I am using -i to ignore case, -w to match whole word and -o

I have found some sort of workaround but was hoping there was a more elegant way of doing this with a single command either awk,egrep,fgrep or other.

```
user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ fgrep -f filea fileb -i -w -o >   test
user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ diff filea test -i
```

5d4
< hostnamee

Comment: On my real word situation - this work around above does not even come close to working like it did in the example above. I am having - and _ in the file-names also and it does not appear to give same results as above.

Comment: Do you want `HOSTNAMEF` to be considered a match to `hostnamef`? I.e. case-insensitive?

Comment: yeah - some backup files in this case example - are done in UPPERCASE while my hostfiles are all lowercase - so HOSTNAMEF should = hostnamef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

- look for "only-matches", i.e. `-o`, of a in b
- use the result as patterns to look for in a, i.e. `-f-`
- only list what does not match, i.e. `-v`

Code:

```
grep -of a.txt b.txt | grep -f- -v a.txt
```

Output:

```
hostnamee
hostnamef
```

Case-insensitive code:

```
grep -oif a.txt b.txt | grep -f- -vi a.txt
```

Output:

```
hostnamee
```

Edit:
Responding to the interesting input by Ed Morton, I have made the sample input somewhat "nastier" to test robustness against substring matches and regex-active characters (e.g. "."):

a.txt:

```
hostnamea
hostnameb
hostnamec
hostnamed
hostnamee
hostnamef
ostname
lilihostnamec
hos.namea
```

b.txt:

```
hostnamea-20170802
hostnameb-20170802 
hostnamec-20170802.xml # some files have extensions
020214-_hostnamed-20170208.tar # some files have different extensions and have different date structure
HOSTNAMEF-20170802
lalahostnamef
hostnameab
stnam
```

This makes things more interesting.
I provide this case insensitive solution:

```
grep -Fwoif a.txt b.txt | grep -f- -Fviw a.txt
```

- additional `-F`, meaning "no regex tricks"
- additional `-w`, meaning "whole word matching"

I find the output quite satisfying, assuming that the following change of the "requirements" is accepted:
Hostnames in "a" only match parts of "b", if all adjoining `_` (and other "word characers" are always considered part of the hostname.
(Note the additional output line of `hostnamed`, which is now not found in "b" anymore, because in "b", it is preceded by an `_`.)
To match possible occurrences of valid hostnames which are preceded/followed by other word characters, the list in "a" would have to explicitly name those variations. E.g. "_hostnamed" would have to be listed in order to not have "hostnamed" in the output. 
(With a little luck, this might even be acceptable for OP, then this extended solution is recommended; for robustness against "EdMortonish traps". Ed, please consider this a compliment on your interesting input, it is not meant in any way negatively.)

Output for "nasty" a and b:

```
hostnamed
hostnamee
ostname
lilihostnamec
hos.namea
```

I am not sure whether the changed handling of `_` still matches OPs goal (if not, within OPs scope the first case insensitive solution is satisfying).
`_` is part of "letter characters" which can be used for "whole word only matching" `-w`. More detailed regex control at some point gets beyond grep, as Ed Morton has mentioned, using awk, perl (sed for masochistic brain exercise, the kind I enjoy) is then appropriate.

With GNU grep 2.5.4 on windows.
The files a.txt and b.txt have your content, I made however sure that they have UNIX line-endings, that is important (at least for a, possibly not for b).

Comment: grep -of file1 file2 -i |grep -f- -v file1 -i ( does this seem the proper way to add ignoring case with your command example)

Comment: I provided a case insensitive version (before noticing your comment question).

Comment: It was a pleasure.

Comment: It;s just bad luck that that is producing the output you want for those specific input files, it will fail with other input. Too bad you accepted it so quickly as that discourages anyone else from providing a different (robust!) answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Could you provide or describe sample input which provokes a failure? I will try to improve the answer based on it.

Comment: try cases where hostnames in one file are substrings of hostnames in the other. try when the hostname in file a is just "tar" or "xml". Lack of anchors and checking specific parts of the fileB hostnames are the issues.

Comment: You're welcome. The simple, clear, robust solution would be a tiny awk script :-).

Comment: Yeah maybe but at that point you're trying to force something to work with grep specifically rather than just trying to come up with the best solution.

Comment: @EdMorton I have extended the solution. Identifying hostnames within "word characters" is not easy and I am unsure whether in awk it is easier. I have specified a "change to requirements", assuming it, I think the goal is achieved.

Comment: Everybody else: Ed is right. Solutions on other tools are of course welcome. I will be interested in anything which gets the "hostname within word characters" solved elegantly. Anything achieving that is likely to get an upvote by me.

Comment: I posted an awk solution. `hostnamed` should not appear in the "nasty" output btw.

Comment: I am going to look at both of these some more - while the solution is working great for me I want it to be a long term solution that grows with additions ect. I do in fact have output files with _ that are not part of the hostname and I am going to come back with some more testing with both these solutions. Thanks alll

Comment: still only solution 1 works - If i try the second solution I get many hosts which exist in file 2

Comment: For both answers (Ed Mortons and mine) you will have to define the syntax   better. For my answer, the syntax around the hostnames is very important. If it is clear, there might be a way to make regex tighter. For Ed Mortons approach you will have to better define the syntax of the hostnames itself, that will allow to make his regexes more generous (so as to allow hostnames containing `_`. Either think about syntax rules, or provide much more sample input.

Comment: well it already works with filenames with _ in it and the very first solution is working perfect. I should probably do some more testing with this but your first answer works great. I do not have any hostnames in filea that have _ so maybe that is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    gsub(/^[^_]+_|-[^-]+$/,"")
    hostnames[tolower($0)]
    next
}
!(tolower($0) in hostnames)

$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
hostnamee

$ awk -f tst.awk b.txt a.txt
hostnamee
ostname
lilihostnamec
hos.namea
```

The only assumption in the above is that your host names don't contain underscores and anything after the last `-` on the line is a date. If that's not the case and there's a better definition of what the optional hostname prefix and suffix strings in fileB can be then just tweak the `gsub()` to use an appropriate regexp.

Comment: Hmm. also needs an assumption. What a pity. But based on that assumption it is as valid a solution as mine is (based on my assumption). Thanks for providing an alternate angle. I think I saw a very early, almost clairvoyant comment, predicting the problem both of us encountered. Pity that it was deleted.

Comment: It only needs an assumption because the OP hasn't told us any way to differentiate hostnames from the prefixes or suffixes. There has to be a robust way but we need the OP to tell us what that is. What it DOESN'T assume is anything about the values of the hostnames which is why it's better than a grep solution. (the evidence for improved robustness being that this does not falsely print `hostnamed` while the greps+pipes solution does :-) ).

Comment: It still works with the ogirinal solution with hostname with _ in it: user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ find /dir -type f -mtime -.9 -printf '%f\n' |fgrep -eacs -eTFTP >fileb  # i put the files into fileb - like host22,hostx,hosty
host22-crappyname-170803-0005.tar.gpg
2017-08-03-00-05-05_hostx_UCM_TFTP.tar
2017-08-03-00-05-05_hosty_UCM_TFTP.tar                                           user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ cat $mh
hosta
hsotb # does not ship the hostx or hosty above with the _ that was in the fileb so it matched and did it's job with matching to file 2 with _'s in it.

Comment: grep -oif "$f2" "$f1" -i | grep -f- -vi "$f2" > "$mh"

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say in the comments but this is simply NOT a job for a chain of greps that'll leave you constantly wondering if you've managed to identify and plug all the holes inherent in not being able to specify exact fields to match on - just use a trivial, robust, portable awk script as I've shown.